# jQuery $get error message: Not Found

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I am running the following jQuery `.get()` call from an HTML page:

```
<div id="fw_results">Results</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get({
        url: "http://fw.localhost:8082/sites/MyPhp/fw.php"
    })
    .success(function(result) {
        $("#fw_results").text(result);
    })
    .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#fw_results").text("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    });
});
</script>
```

and the `fw_result div` content is populated with:

```
Error: error Not Found
```

When I call fw.localhost:8082/sites/MyPhp/fw.php from my browser, I get the proper result.

How come I get a "Not Found" error message? Is there any way to find more information about the cause of this issue?

**Update**

From Firebug, I see a call to **/sites/MyJS/src/main/webapp/html/%5Bobject%20Object%5D** that fails. I don't know what `%5Bobject%20Object%5D` could be. I am trying to find out.

**Update II**

For the records, although I though I had gotten rid of the issue, because I moved the code in a Drupal content type instance (yes, this issue happens within a Drupal installation), in fact it appeared again. In the end, it has nothing to do with Drupal.

One just needs to change this:

```
$.get({
    url: "http://fw.localhost:8082/sites/MyPhp/fw.php"
})
```

into this:

```
$.get("http://fw.localhost:8082/sites/MyPhp/fw.php")
```

to get rid of this error.

Comment: If you watch the resource call in Firebug (or your tool of choice) is there any more useful information in the request/response?

Comment: Is `http://fw.localhost:8082/sites/MyPhp/fw.php` located at a different path from that of the page? There are security restrictions in JavaScript, so if it thinks it's from a different domain it will restrict it.

Comment: Most likely this is cross domain, you may need to use JSONP?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with developer tools in Chrome or Firefox?  I would look at the Network tab to make sure the request URI from the ajax request is what you think it is.

Also, check your web servers error logs ... that might also have some useful information to help you track down the problem.

Comment: My original page is at: http://fw.localhost:8082/sites/MyJS/src/main/webapp/html/fw_request.html, so I guess it would be the same domain no?

Comment: If it helps, that last section of the call causing the error is `[object object]`.  %5B and %5D are square brackets, and %20 is a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well for starters you could try debugging the success callback of the jquery .get using firefox firebug

edit:
first of all make sure you download and install firebug from http://getfirebug.com/
after you have in installed, press f12 to activate the firebug console, make sure you go to the scripts tab and click the enable button. A page refresh will be required afterwards.

After the page has reloaded and all scripts are monitored by firebug, you can select from the scripts menu the js file that contains your jquery get, click the js file in the scripts dropdown and put a breakpoint at the success callback (do that by clicking on the left of the line that has the success callback). See if this helps you.

Comment: this might not solve your problem but at least it can put you on track to debugging it. let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: Fact is, this page is called from within a Drupal web site. So instead of using a separate HTML page in the directory structure, I put the HTML call in a node content as Full HTML and I don't get the error anymore.